# regex to match 3-digit numbers but not 4-digit ones

Tags: regex, osx-yosemite

I have a file that contains either 3-digit numbers or 4-digit numbers within some strings. I want to be able to choose only the 3-digit ones. 
I tried the following:

```
`[0-9][0-9][0-9]` or `\d{3}`
```

which naturally matches the 4-digit ones as well. And `\d{3}` doesn't match anything.

I also want to select the 3 digits only. Is there a way to exclude the characters before and after the 3 digit number from the selection?

How can I achieve this? I want to be able to use `sed` and `grep`.

Comment: Did you try `\b\d{3}\b`?

Comment: I just did, that doesn't work as well. I checked that `\d` works on its own, but not with `{3}` near it. Also the numbers don't necessarily have any blanks around them.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. How do you use this regex? In a program (what language do you use)? In a shell script (what shell? I assume bash)? Do you want to use it with `grep` or `sed` or other command line program? Each of these has its own quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex

```
\b[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]*\b
```

should do your task.
Trying it out by entering

```
echo 123 | egrep '\b[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]]{3}[[:alpha:]]*\b'
```

works for `123`, whereas `1234`, `a1323` are not accepted. If you want to use `sed` (`{3}` seemingly did not work here), you can try

```
sed -e 's/\(\b[[:alpha:]]*\)\([[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\)\(\b[[:alpha:]]*\)/\2/'
```

The regex matches only three-digit-numbers and removes the word-parts before and after.

Comment: I'm sorry my question was not clear enough initially. I have made an edit. I want to be able to select the numbers in `a123b` but not `a` and `b`.